# Slow/restricted internet speed on Ubuntu 14 (driver/hardare issue?)?

Tags: drivers, network-adapter, internet-speed, ubuntu-14.04

I recently built my own desktop and I have noticed that it consistently gets ~ .8 mbps download speed when on the ethernet and slightly better when using wifi. I have run several tests that can confirm this is specifically this Desktops issue - not my ISP, Router, etc. Our internet speed is rated at 3 mbps and all other computers, hardwired or wireless, consistently test out anywhere from 2.2 to 3 mbps.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

This command: `lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %` returned this:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

By reading other forums and whatnot, I have decided it most likely is a driver issue or network card issue. However, I am open to suggestions. Thanks!